# getting error in the code given below after updating the flutter app to Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2

Tags: flutter, graphql

can't assign httpLink to link.

```
static HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    uri: " .."
  );
  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client1 = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(cache: InMemoryCache(), link: httpLink//error is here
),
  );
```

error: The argument type 'HttpLink' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Link'. (argument_type_not_assignable

Comment: Did you try something like `link: httpLink as Link`?

Comment: Now its showing me error of undefined Location.

Comment: Have you imported the library for `Link`?

Comment: I don't know why but it's working as :- 
static Link link = httpLink as Link;
  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client1 = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(cache: InMemoryCache(), link: link),
  );
not as:-  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client1 = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(cache: InMemoryCache(), link:  httpLink as Link),
  );

Comment: Thanks though CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 0):

@CopsOnRoad resolved the initial question - for `undefined location`, you need to make sure the server is running and accessible from the environment you're running in.

See [this issue](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/issues/212) for help troubleshooting